# How do I create a new server on AWS without a pem key?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I don't like pem keys. Coworkers are reckless and they put pem keys in s3 and cloud drives.

I can use password based authentication by starting the server with user data with a startup script.

But I noticed, you can see all the authentication data added in the startup script by clicking the server and selecting view user data. That is baaad.

Best way I have thought of is to create a pem key and then delete it after server is created, then delete it from amazon pem key list.

Any better way to start a server without using pem keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is:

- Launch an instance
- `ssh` into the instance and create a password for the user. For example, ubuntu user
- You can create accounts for other users too if you prefer
- Edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and set:

  PubkeyAuthentication no

  PasswordAuthentication yes
- Restart the ssh service: `sudo service ssh restart`
- Try `ssh` into the instance with password
- Create an AMI from that instance
- Launch new instances from that AMI and not specify a keypair

Answer (score 1):

The notion that password authentication is in any sense a better idea than keys is truly preposterous.

The original key shouldn't generally be used routinely, it's just the initial mechanism of access.

The seemingly obvious solution is something like this.

- The developers create their own *personal* keypairs with `ssh-keygen`.  The private key is not to be stored outside their individual control or disclosed to any one for any reason.
- The developers provide you with their public keys.  If they are careless with any private key, but perhaps particularly the private half of their own keypair, they should be summarily dismissed.
- You append their public keys to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.
- Anyone in possession of any one of the private keys matching the public keys in this file can access the instance over SSH.

You can, of course, do this in instance user metadata, because public keys are not secrets.  Possession of a public key gives you exactly nothing of value. Or add them later.

Answer (score 0):

When you create an EC2 instance, all the way at the end of the dialog there is a pop-up window in which you can configure your pem-key. In the drop-down list, it also gives you the opportunity to chose "Proceed without a key pair". 
That should do it. 
Although I wouldn't do that.

Comment: I know that one. But then, only way to add credentials is through a userdata startup script, which anyone with AWS console access can see. You can only wipe the user data it if you stop the servers. Between that time credentials are visible to all.